# Label emails in Gmail based on content compared to date sent?

Tags: gmail

I need to automatically flag emails as older than 24 hours, but with respect to the time they were first received by the sender. Here's the breakdown:
- Sender receives email from an unrelated address (i.e., not the address I'm working in)
- The reply-to for their email is my email address, so when they reply it comes to me
- I need to compare the timestamp from their original email (which is only included in the message content as far as I can tell, given the above) to the time at which they send it to me and determine if that is greater than 24 hours

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/